# Show and Hide div for shortening the text that comes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem where we have to show/hide some text in the product description in the product detail page. The description has to be shortened upto desired number of lines and by clicking on "more" complete description is to be shown. I thought of implementing it as shown in the jQuery link below:

> http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/jquery.shorten.1.0.js

And the code is as follows:

```
jQuery.fn.shorten = function (settings) {
    var config = {
        showChars: 100,
        ellipsesText: "...",
        moreText: "more",
        lessText: "less"
    };

    if(settings) {
        $.extend(config, settings);
    }

    $('.morelink').live('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('less')) {
            $this.removeClass('less');
            $this.html(config.moreText);
        } else {
            $this.addClass('less');
            $this.html(config.lessText);
        }
        $this.parent().prev().toggle();
        $this.prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var content = $this.html();
        if(content.length > config.showChars) {
            var c = content.substr(0, config.showChars);
            var h = content.substr(config.showChars, content.length - config.showChars);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + config.ellipsesText + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript://nop/" class="morelink">' + config.moreText + '</a></span>';
            $this.html(html);
            $(".morecontent span").hide();
        }
    });
};
```

I have inserted the following code in base.tpl

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".comment").shorten();
}); 
</script>
```

I have given the following class in corresponding html file:

```
<div class="comment">  
   <!-- Link for getting the description from backend -->
</div >
```

Since the details are coming from the backend,the underlying dynamic divs and also the unordered lists inside it are not getting effected please suggest me some ways to implement this functionality.

Comment: how about you call .shorten(); after you insert the dynamic divs? i.e. in success function of you ajax call.

Comment: I aree with @UmairP - call shorten() after the content has been pulled in to the page.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we do in our portal is use the text-overflow css property.  You can define a height for your description box and then use a class similar to this to give you the ellipsis indicating there is more to read.

```
.flo
{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You could then add a read more button, or click to expand type of deal which will then expand the content to be seen in full.  Just thinking in my head but if you laid out your html right you might even be able to use CSS to expand the size of the description box on :hover or your description could be  tags for checkboxes and when you click the label it sets the checkboxes :checked state allowing your css to expand your description.

Just a couple other way to approach your issue. Please comment if you have any questions..